# C# WinForms Trying to Update UI with Timer but without slowing the performance down

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer, mschart

so currently I've got an application that has 2 processes. One process is pining, while pinging the process is writing down the results into an array.

Another process is for updating the UI every second with a timer. Whats being update is an mschart to be more exact.

That's how I have set up the timer:

```
readonly System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
myTimer.Interval = 1000;
myTimer.Tick += WriteFunction;
```

Now this is the method that I'm calling every second for refreshing the UI / actually Graph:

```
 private void WriteFunction(object objectInfo, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (NetPinger.source.AddGraph b in graphList)
            {
                b.fileRead();
            }
        }
```

The method, for updating the chart is inside another class, and looks like this:

```
    public void fileRead()
    {
        double unixTimestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;

        chart_holder.Series[0].Points.Clear();

        for (double i = unixTimestamp; unixTimestamp - graphSizing < i; i--)
        {
            bool exists;
            try
            {
                exists = Array.Exists(file, element => element.XValue == i);
                exists = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                exists = false;
            }
            try
            {

                if (exists == false)
                {
                    DataPoint point = new DataPoint(i, 0);
                    chart_holder.Series[0].Points.Add(point);
                }
                else
                {
                    DataPoint point = Array.Find(file, element => element.XValue == i);
                    chart_holder.Series[0].Points.Add(point);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ex));
            }
        }
    }
```

Now what I noticed was that if the graphSizing (number that I'm looping through) is kept low, the performance is kinda fine and everything is sync (multiple graphs from UI are updated at same time etc.) like it should be. But as soon as i rise it let's say to like 50 or even 250 (what the goal should be) the UI and Graph updating are being very very slow. It's only updating like every 3s and the UI is in general very laggy and slow.

Does anyone has any advice how I can maintain good performance or where I messed up that the UI is so slow? For further questions or more details feel free to ask.

Thanks a lot for your time and helping.

Greetings C.User

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` runs on the gui thread.So invoke is useless here. That's why is doesn't relieve the GUI thread. If you want to load multiple files simultaneously, take a look at the [`Parallel.Foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop)

Comment: in `private void WriteFunction(object objectInfo, EventArgs e)` what purpose parameters are serving?

Comment: @Amit I added the parameters so I could run the method with the timer.

Comment: @C.User of course so why `Invoke(new NetPinger.source.AddGraph.ReturnAddGraph2(WriteFunction), new object[] { b });` ? you can always invoke such method which doesn't required dummy arguments

Comment: @J.vanLangen you're right, the invoke is not need - I removed it!

Comment: Every time you go thru the loop there is a cost when declaring a variable inside the loop. Especially when you need to create it with the `new()`command.

Comment: when you do lots of updates on a form or control, like in a loop, windows will not do each update immediate for you, but wait for some iddle time. You can always force this by the `Update()`statement, that will make your form  look more responsive, but will again slow the loop down

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code always runs in the UI thread, since `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` calls the delegate on the UI thread. Even if that where not the case (and you used System.Timer instead), you delegate everything back to the UI with your Invoke call. You need to make sure you prepare the data on another thread first and do as little as possible in the UI thread itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm going to try to solve my problem with this advice. With "preparing the data" you are referring to the looping through the file, right?

Comment: @C.User: Correct, and do all the processing there (like updating the data points for the table)

Comment: It might be possible to add multiple points afterwards if the `chart_holder.Series[0].Points` is depending on the gui thread updates. So process all the points first and add them in bulk.